# Will a 1/4 20 nut fit a tripod plate with a 1/4 20 bolt?

Tags: tripod, tripod-socket

I ordered from China off the net a 1/4 20 butterfly nut, but it does not fit the 1/4 20 bolt on the tripod plate. Do I need a bigger nut size? I was under the impression the same size nut should fit. Any tips? Or is the ordered nut faulty?

Comment: Did you seriously order a single nut from China?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it does not fit"? Does it get difficult to turn after a few turns? Does it even start? Is the nut left-hand threaded?

Comment: What sort of tripod plate? Some tripods use 3/8" screw thread.

Comment: It's a 1/4 20 for sure. The nut does not even start! I think WayneF could be right. It may not have been UNC.

Comment: re null, yes I ordered a winged nut as I am in the EU, and did not find any UNC threads in the stores, only metric ones.

Comment: PS The reason I know it is 1/4 20 is because I also ordered a converter between 1/4 20 and 3/8 from China as well and that one works fine (the smaller hole that is 1/4 20 fits the tripod plate screw) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From China, it may be metric then, or at least not 1/4-20 if it does not fit.  1/4-20 is the standard tripod screw thread, which should fit by definition.

Full name of thread is UNC  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Thread_Standard

If in North America, try the local hardware store.

Comment: Take the bolt along with you when you go to the store. This way you can try if the nut fits.

Comment: Thx, I am in the EU, and I tried a few stores, but they only have metric stuff. :)

Answer (score 2):

Most tripods are 1/4 and 20 UNC threads, but some bigger cameras have a 3/8ths and 16 UNC thread so tripods exist that have on their head.  If what you're looking at though is the base of a tripod,  i.e. just the legs and the top plate, but no ball mount or anything (what is often called the "head") then those are USUALLY 3/8.   When you buy a tripod head,  it has a 3/8 female at the bottom to connect to the actual tripod, then the 1/4 on the top to connect to the camera.